# How can I set the size of the gap between inline elements in CSS?

Tags: css

I am creating an MVC 1.0 form to use in multiple views.  I have some elements that need to be shown on the same line, and I have done this by setting the display to "display: inline" for the style.  I have also added the margin-left setting to the CSS in order to force the gap between the inline elements but this doesn't appear to be being set.

My CSS has:

fieldset label.inline 
{
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 2em;
}

The view code is:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Details</legend>
    <p>
        <label for="StartTime">Start Time:</label>
        <%= Html.TextBox("StartTime", Model.StartTime.ToShortTimeString())%>
        <label for="NextDay" class="inline">Next Day?</label>
        <%= Html.CheckBox("NextDay") %>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessage("StartTime", "*")%>
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

Setting the size in the "margin-left" style has no impact on the space between the StartTime control and the NextDay label.  How can I create this gap between the elements?

Comment: Can you show us the actual HTML that is output to the browser?

Comment: Re-tagged as CSS. The fact that this is an MVC view isn't relevant to the question, which is strictly related to HTML and CSS.

Comment: I have now changed my "margin-left: 2em" setting in the style sheet to "padding-left: 4em" and still don't see a gap before the NextDay label.

The HTML output is:

<p>
    <label for="StartTime">Start Time:</label>
    <input id="StartTime" name="StartTime" type="text" value="00:00" />
    <label for="NextDay" class="inline">Next Day?</label>
    <input id="NextDay" name="NextDay" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="NextDay" type="hidden" value="false" />
</p>

This is in IE7.

Answer (score 1):

Use display: inline-block;

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you testing in?

If you're using Firefox, use the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) extension. Use the pointer tool to select one of your elements, and then use the Layout tab to look at the box model. That will show you the padding, border and margins that are being applied. If you post the HTML being generated and the box model properties that are being calculated you might get better answers.

Comment: The style being applied (as shown in Firebug) is:

fieldset label.inline {
display:inline;
padding-left:4em;
}

so as I'd expect.

The HTML is:

<p>    
    <label for="StartTime">Start Time:</label>   
    <input id="StartTime" name="StartTime" type="text" value="00:00" />  
    <label for="NextDay" class="inline">Next Day?</label>  
    <input id="NextDay" name="NextDay" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="NextDay" type="hidden" value="false" />  
</p>  

It isn't being shown as right-aligned in IE.  It is in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

The "margin" style works different for inline elements. You can use the "inline-block" display-mode:

```
fieldset label.inline { display: inline-block; margin-left: 2em; }
```

Comment: inline-box is not a css property. You probably mean inline-block. Altough there is a firefox specific -moz-inline-box.

Comment: I have now tried

fieldset label.inline 
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 4em;
    padding-left: 4em;
}

but still without success.